# Cambiar dinámicamente el titulo de Highcharts con Jquery

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Necesito que al cambiar la opción de un `select` cambie el titulo de Highcharts automáticamente.
He estado probando varias formas de mostrarlo y no he podido dar con la configuración correcta.

**HTML**

```
<tr>  
  <td width="150" align="right"><font face="arial"><b>AÑO</b></font></td>
  <td>
    <select name="ANO_ACTA" id="ANO_ACTA" autofocus="autofocus">
      <option>Seleccione...</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td width="150" align="right"><font face="arial"><b>MES</b></font></td>
  <td>
    <select name="MES_ACTA" id="MES_ACTA">
      <option>Seleccione...</option>
      <option value="ENERO">ENERO</option>
      <option value="FEBRERO">FEBRERO</option>
      <option value="MARZO">MARZO</option>
      <option value="ABRIL">ABRIL</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'spline'
},

title: {
  text: '<b></b>Seleccione y Año y Mes...</b>'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Informe Rollout Mensual'
},

series: [

{
  name : "VALLE",
  data: [],
  }
}
}]
});

$( "#MES_ACTA" ).change(function() {
var ANO_ACTA = $('#ANO_ACTA').val();
var MES_ACTA = $('#MES_ACTA').val();

$.ajax({
  url: "procesar.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { ANO_ACTA: ANO_ACTA, MES_ACTA: MES_ACTA},
  dataType: "json"
})

.done(function(data) {

  console.log(data);

  chart.series[0].setData(data[0]); 

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: ¿Y el código HTML del select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado necesitas acceder al contenido de la opción seleccionada con [jQuery.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
 $("#id option:selected").text();
```

Donde `id` es el atributo `id` del `<select>`.

Y luego necesitas cambiar el título usando [chart.setTitle()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setTitle):

```
chart.setTitle({text: "Seleccionado: <b>" + $("#id option:selected").text() + "</b>"});
```

Presuponiendo que es el `id` que espera el evento del cambio:

```
$( "#MES_ACTA" ).change(function() {
    chart.setTitle({text: "Seleccionado: <b>" + $("#MES_ACTA option:selected").text() + "</b>"});
    /* ... */
}
```